# (ASP.NET ) multiple buttons in a single form and want to access the clicked button id

Tags: forms

the idea is to register an employee in one of the listed courses . each course has and id 
retrieved from my DB and display a register button . if the course is full a waiting button  shows with the id of the course.

now i want to get the clicked button id to insert it in the DB .

```
 <form   method="post" action="**to current page**">

<input  type="submit" name="btnWait"" value="register" ID="003"/>
<input  type="submit" name="btnWait"" value="register" ID="004"/>

<input  type="submit" name="btnWait"" value="wait" ID="005"/>
<input  type="submit" name="btnWait"" value="wait" ID="006"/>
```

I TRIED THIS , BUT DID NOT WORK 
i know it is not right but :(

```
<%
     If (Request.Form("btnRegister") = "register") Then
         MsgBox(Request("id"))
     ElseIf (Request.Form("btnWait") = "wait") Then
         MsgBox("wait")
     End If


 %>


</form>
```

Comment: Define "did not work."  Was there an item in the form collection with the specified key?  What value did that item have?  (Also, what do you expect `MsgBox()` to do in a web application?  Doesn't that pop up a message in a WinForms application?)

Comment: Are you actually using ASP.NET or are you using classic ASP? The code above could go either way, and from your comment to the answer below, that shouldn't really be the way you are writing ASP.NET code.

Answer (score 1):

instead pf `<input  type="submit" name="btnWait"" value="register" ID="003"/>` you can use:
`<asp:button id="003" runat="server" text=register" />`

and then in the code behind file:

```
Button clickedbutton = (Button)sender;

if(clickedbutton.ID.Equals(003))
{
  //your piece of code
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Laziale for your answer, what I do i retrieve all the courses from the DB and then use response.write("<input.....>") + for loop    to display each button corresponding to the course title